# Better word for "specialized"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

***General*** relativity is a general concept that apples to  that applies to the universe at large. ***Special* relativity** is a *"subset"* of general relativity that applies to the subset of the universe that shares a certain characteristic.

"Subset" is not the right word here - what's a word that addresses the conceptual relationship between a "general concept" and a *"special(ized)"* application of that concept to a more strictly-defined context?

Comment: A subset of? A kind of?

Comment: @Cerberus please see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[aspect](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aspect) seems appropriate here:

> a distinct feature or element in a problem, situation

or

> part; feature; phase, as of a subject or problem.

or

> nature; quality; character

You can also use *type*

Comment: please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

**Categorization**

cat·e·go·rize  [kat-i-guh-rahyz]
verb (used with object), cat·e·go·rized, cat·e·go·riz·ing.
1.
to arrange in categories or classes; classify.
2.
to describe by labeling or giving a name to; characterize.

Comment: please see edit.